# How to add days to java.sql.date?

Tags: java, date

Here is my program, I tried

```
java.sql.Date logicalDate;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(logicalDate); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

The line below is showing an error the constructor Date(date) is undefined

```
java.sql.Date startDate= new java.sql.Date(c.getTime());
```

How do I add 1 day to java.sql.Date logicalDate?

Comment: import java.util.Calendar for OP's code snippet

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Calendar#getTime` returns a `java.util.Date` representation of the `Calendar`.  You really need to use [`Calendar#getTimeInMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) instead

```
java.sql.Date startDate= new java.sql.Date(c.getTimeInMillis())
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method

```
private Date sqlDatePlusDays(Date date, int days) {
    return Date.valueOf(date.toLocalDate().plusDays(days));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Never use the terrible legacy classes `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, and `java.util.Date`. Use only *java.time* classes.

> How do I add 1 day to java.sql.Date logicalDate?

Convert from legacy class `java.sql.Date` to modern class `java.time.LocalDate`. Then call `plus…`/`minus…` methods to add/subtract days, weeks, months, or years.

```
myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 )
```

If given a `Calendar` that is actually a `GregorianCalendar`, and you want only the date, convert to `ZonedDateTime` and extract a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
( (GregorianCalendar) myCal )   // Cast from general `Calendar` to more concrete class `GregorianCalendar`. 
.toZonedDateTime()              // Convert from the legacy class to the modern `ZonedDateTime` class replacement.
.toLocalDate()                  // Extract the date only, omitting the time-of-day and the time zone.
.plusWeeks( 1 )                 // Returns a `LocalDate` object, a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
```

## *java.time*

The badly designed `java.sql.Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes with the [unanimous adoption](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=5639) of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Avoid `Calendar` class too.

Retrieve from your database with [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) by calling [`ResultSet::getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class)).

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Add a week by calling [`LocalDate::plusWeeks`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusWeeks(long)).

```
LocalDate weekLater = ld.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

Write to database by calling [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , weekLater ) ;
```

Best to avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes entirely. But if you need a [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html) object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, use new conversion methods added to the old classes. Specifically, [`java.sql.Date.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDate)).

```
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        java.sql.Date todaysDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

        int futureDay =1;
        int pastDay=2;

        java.sql.Date futureDate = this.addDays(todaysDate, futureDay);
        java.sql.Date pastDate = this.subtractDays(todaysDate, pastDay);

        System.out.println("futureDate =>>> " + futureDate);
        System.out.println("pastDate =>>> " + pastDate);


    }

    public static Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
        return new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    public static Date subtractDays(Date date, int days) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
        return new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Calendar cNow = Calendar.getInstance();  
        Date dNow = cNow.getTime();  
        cNow.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  

        Date dSeven = cNow.getTime();  

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");  

        String dateNow = format.format(dNow);  
        String dayBefore = format.format(dSeven);  
        System.out.println(dateNow);  
        System.out.println(daySeven); //here is your current day + 7  

        Date date = new Date();  
        System.out.println(date);
```