# How to subtract days in scala?

Tags: scala

I parsed a string to a date:

```
val deathTime = "2019-03-14 05:22:45"
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val deathDate = new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(deathtime).getTime)
```

Now, I want to subtract 30 days from deathDate. How to do that? I have tried

```
deathDate.minusDays(30)
```

It does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802010/how-to-add-days-to-java-sql-date

Comment: never say "it does not work" when asking for help, say whether you got an error message or unexpected behavior, and exactly what the error or behavior was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are java8 then you can decode the date as [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). `LocalDateTime` allows operations on dates - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusDays-long-

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDateTime

scala> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

scala> val deathTime = "2019-03-14 05:22:45"
deathTime: String = 2019-03-14 05:22:45

scala> val deathDate = LocalDateTime.parse(deathTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
deathDate: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2019-03-14T05:22:45

scala> deathDate.minusDays(30)
res1: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2019-02-12T05:22:45
```

Also see [Java: Easiest Way to Subtract Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532371/432903)

Answer (score 6):

If your requirement is to do with data-frame in spark-scala.

```
 df.select(date_add(lit(current_date),-30)).show
+-----------------------------+
|date_add(current_date(), -30)|
+-----------------------------+
|                   2019-03-02|
+-----------------------------+
```

`date_add` function with negative value or `date_sub` with positive value can do the desired.

Comment: I think OP is a scala question instead of scala spark question.